# Is there a way to show a badge icon for Reminders app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios, reminders

Maybe it is possible but I'm doing something wrong.

I want to know the total number of reminders for the day by just glancing at the icon. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Apple decided not to show one so there isn't.

Comment: maybe there is jailbreak tweak that enables it, or at least shows them on notification panel??

Comment: I know that this question is a bit old, but to answer your question, there is on, er, that version of iOS that is currently under NDA. See [here](http://www.cultofmac.com/173126/new-in-ios-6-more-emoji-icons-banners-for-new-apps-badges-for-reminders-app/) for more info.

Comment: @gtm Ehh... It's ancient question lol:))

Answer (score 2):

Badges now show for reminders as of iOS 6, released September 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it no, not using the Apple app anyway.

Let them know you want it: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post at Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/173126/new-in-ios-6-more-emoji-icons-banners-for-new-apps-badges-for-reminders-app/), that functionality will be coming with iOS 6, which will be shipping this fall.